# Is it possible to solve this equation for $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have the following equation:
$$
\cos\left(\sqrt{G^2 - 2 × G × \frac{\cos(x)}{\cos(α)} + \tan(α)^2} + b\right) \\
+ \sqrt{G^2 - 2 × G × \frac{\cos(x)}{\cos(α)} + \tan(α)^2} × \sin\left(\sqrt{G^2 - 2 × G × \frac{\cos(x)}{\cos(α)} + \tan(α)^2} + b\right) \\
= \frac{\cos(G)}{\cos(α)} - G × \cos(x - G)
$$

where

- $b := α - \tan(α)$
- $G := \frac{2}{Z} × F × \sec(α)$

I want to solve for $x$ in terms of $α$, $F$, and $Z$. Is that possible?

I tried putting it into WolframScript with the command `Solve[Cos[Sqrt[G^2 - 2 * G * Cos[x]/Cos[a] + Tan[a]^2] + H] + Sqrt[G^2 - 2 * G * Cos[x]/Cos[a] + Tan[a]^2] * Sin[Sqrt[G^2 - 2 * G * Cos[x]/Cos[a] + Tan[a]^2] + H] == Cos[G]/Cos[a] - G * Cos[x - G], x]`, but while it didn't outright say the problem is *not* solvable like it has with previous things I've tried, it also hasn't produced a solution after running for over an hour.

The fact that WolframScript doesn't say there's no solution gives me hope, but I don't know how else to attack this problem.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but owing to the complexity of the expression the solution may not be tidy (I say "may not" because I have no intention of wrangling with that at this hour in the morning!) I think the best way to start would be to replace every single term not directly involving $cos(x)$ using single arbitrary symbols and then once you have an expression for $x$ to simply substitute the original terms back in. You'll also want to use the angle difference formula for $cos(x)$ on the RHS.

Comment: Defining $$b:=a-\tan a\qquad Z_2:=Z/2\qquad G:=\frac{F}{Z_2\cos a}$$ $$\begin{align}P_x&:=\frac{\sqrt{F^2-2FZ_2\cos x+Z_2^2\sin^2 a}}{Z_2 \cos a}\\ &= \frac{\sqrt{G^2\cos^2a-2G\cos a\cos x+\sin^2 a}}{\cos a}
\end{align}$$ (where I'm using the subscript on $P_x$ as a reminder that it's not constant, while the other values are) cause your equation to reduce to
$$\cos(P_x+b)+P_x\sin(P_x+b)=\frac{\cos G}{\cos a} - G \cos\left(x - G\right)$$ Having $P_x$ appear both *inside* and *outside* of the trig functions on the left doesn't bode well for symbolic solvability.